# How do I insert the following into my custom table?

Tags: join-tables

```
$service = array(
'show_option_all'    => 'Select your Service',
'show_option_none'   => '',
'option_none_value'  => '-1',
'orderby'            => 'name',
'order'              => 'ASC',
'show_count'         => 0,
'hide_empty'         => 1,
'child_of'           => 0,
'exclude'            => '',
'include'            => '',
'echo'               => 1,
'selected'           => '',
'hierarchical'       => 0,
'name'               => 'reliable-cat',
'id'                 => '',
'class'              => 'postform',
'depth'              => 0,
'tab_index'          => 1,
'taxonomy'           => 'category',
'hide_if_empty'      => false,
'value_field'        => 'name',
);
$area = array(
'show_option_all'    => 'Select your Area',
'show_option_none'   => '',
'option_none_value'  => '-1',
'orderby'            => 'name',
'order'              => 'ASC',
'show_count'         => 0,
'hide_empty'         => 1,
'child_of'           => 0,
'exclude'            => '',
'include'            => '',
'echo'               => 1,
'selected'           => '',
'hierarchical'       => 0,
'name'               => 'reliable-tag',
'id'                 => '',
'class'              => 'postform',
'depth'              => 0,
'tab_index'          => 2,
'taxonomy'           => 'post_tag',
'hide_if_empty'      => false,
'value_field'        => 'name',
);

if(isset($_POST['reliable-search-submit-button'])){
    global $wpdb;
    $table = $wpdb->prefix . "custom_search_tracker";
    $data = array(
        'cst_service' => esc_attr($_POST['search-service']),
        'cst_area' => esc_attr($_POST['search-area']),
        );
    $subscribe = $wpdb -> insert($table, $data);
}
```

The code to insert the data.

```
<form name="reliable-search-form" id="reliable-search-form" method="POST" action="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/search-results/">
<div id="reliable-service"><input type="text" id="search-service" name="search-service" value="<?php wp_dropdown_categories($service); ?>" /></div><!-- #reliable-service -->
<div id="reliable-area"><input type="text" id="search-area" name="search-area" value="<?php wp_dropdown_categories($area); ?>" /></div><!-- #reliable-area -->
<div id="reliable-search-submit-form"><input type="submit" id="reliable-search-submit-button" name="reliable-search-submit-button" value="Search" /></div><!-- #reliable-submit-form -->
</form>
```

Nothing gets inserted into the table. I have used this code for a subscription list and it works so I want to know why it isnt working here.

Comment: Where is that first block of code? What is `/search-results/`? A page?

Comment: Hi, search-results is a page. I have updated my question with the first block of code.

Comment: Doesn't answer my question. Where is it? functions.php? A plugin?

Comment: My apologies. All that code is on the custom search form.

Answer (score -1):

The reason why it wasn't working was because of my form action. I moved the code to insert data to the search results page and it added the the data to the table like I needed.